# How to extract specific elements from a filename?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I have a bunch of files in the following format:

```
2014-11-19.8.ext
2014-11-26.1.ext
2014-11-26.2.blah.ext
2014-11-26_3.ext
2014-11-26.4.stuff_here.ext
2014-12-03.1. could be anything.ext
2014-12-032b.ext
2014-11-26 613 adva.ext
```

My goal is to iterate over the entire list of files and to take the date formatting from `YYYY-MM-DD` and store that in a variable in the format of `YYYYMMDD` for further processing (in my case It's going to be pushed into a `touch` command).

So normally I would match against this regular expression: `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*`

And then use `$1$2$3` to get my desired pattern, however I'm not sure how to do this in `bash` / `zsh`.

How can this be done within a shell script as such?

Comment: @Sundeep that latter option is better wrt parameter expansion. So how does that work precisely? Right now in your example you get the `YYYY` and `MM`, but then you just grab the rest with `${f:8}`, when I would rather just grab `DD` and discard `.*` (everything after `DD`).

Comment: Please, could you post an desired output? Or is your goal to rename files?

Comment: @JohnGoofy please note my edit from ~30 min ago and the answer that Sundeep gave.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ touch 2014-11-19.8.ext 2014-11-26.1.ext
$ for f in *.ext; do d="${f:0:4}${f:5:2}${f:8:2}"; echo "$d"; done
20141119
20141126
```

- `${f:0:4}` means 4 characters starting from index `0` and `f` is variable name
- replace `echo "$d"` with your code

Comment: Interesting, so the "cursor" is on the index and is not inclusive, but rather exclusive. so in this case `5:2` starts at the 1st dash, but does not include it. `8:2` starts at the 2nd dash and does not include it. Very interesting and great to know.

Comment: `0` is starting index... so the first `-` index is `4`...

Comment: I always think of indices as pointing *between* characters instead of at them. The oddball case is then requesting a single character, in which case the index is short for "between that index and the subsequent index", i.e. the character right of that index.

Answer (score 5):

To loop over every file in the current directory and compare their filenames to the desired pattern, then set a variable containing the date pieces

```
for f in *
do 
  [[ $f =~ ^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])(.*) ]] && 
  yourvar="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

This uses [bash's `[[` ability to use regular expression matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) to place the date pieces into the BASH_REMATCH array.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it interactively by using `GNU sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}.*\)/\1\2\3/g' stuff.txt
```

For multiple files (if in same directory and no other considered files in directory):

```
for file in *
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
          sed 's/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1\2\3/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Okay, nice, but I'm personally liking the conciseness of the comments that @Sundeep is leaving above where you seem to have more readable control over the fields. My goal here is to extract out these elements and then use them in another command (specifically I'm setting times via `touch`).  Not quite sure why he's not starting it of as an answer instead of comments...

Comment: You can e.g. pipe the output to another command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `zsh` way of doing this, without loops:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -n '([0-9](#c4))-([0-9](#c2))-([0-9](#c2))(*)' '$1$2$3$4'
```

- `[0-9](#c4)` means any digit repeated 4 times
- `$1`-`$2` refer to previously used parenthesis
- `-n` prevents execution (only prints), remove this flag if you are happy with the result

As `zsh` takes care of globbing all corner cases (whitespaces, special characters, etc) should be taken automatically into account.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on GNU Coreutils, you have this:

```
$ date --date=2014-11-13 +"%Y%m%d"
20141113
```

However:

```
$ date --date=2014-11-130ABCJUNK +"%Y%m%d"
date: invalid date ‘2014-11-130ABCJUNK’
```

So the task is much simpler: extact the first ten characters of each `YYYY-MM-DDetc` filename to get the date by itself, then pass to `date` for reformatting.

But, if we are on GNU Coreutils, we can skip the `date` command because `touch` has the exact same `--date=STRING` option.

```
for file in * ; do
  date=${file%${file##??????????}} # chop all but first ten
  touch --date=$date -- "$file"
done
```

But why do this ten character chopping in the POSIX portable way when we are relying on `touch` to be from GNU Coreutils?

```
for file in * ; do
  date=${file:0:10}
  touch --date=$date -- "$file"
done
```

Comment: I was told by someone that `touch` required `YYYYMMDD` only format when the `-t` parameter was issued...

Comment: @ylluminate: `-t` requires [[cc]yy]mmddhhmm[.ss] -- which is not the same as you wrote, although it does omit punctuation other than possibly one dot -- but _in the GNU version_ (as clearly stated) `--date` (or `-d`) is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try pattern substitution:

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

parameter is the basename of the file.
pattern is a dash. In this /- to replace pattern globally.
string is empty, since you want delete the dashes.

```
mv "${f}" "${f//-/}"
```

Caveat:
I didn't get this working with the case of spaces in the extention.

Comment: So in this case I'm wanting to not only delete the dashes, but everything after the `DD` in the pattern.  The goal is to extract YYYYMMDD to use in a `touch` command following getting the correct pattern as I'm going to leave the filename itself intact and just pull out the dating for filesystem timestamp setting. Might see above comments by @Sundeep so far as they're close, but I'm not following the actual logic so far in the parameter expansion chain for the end.

Comment: @ylluminate you could do a two-step substitution like `for f in *.ext; do d="${f%%.*}"; echo "${d//-}"; done` though, (first remove the longest trailing string, then remove the dashes).